# OnSubscribe position causes OnComplete event to fire prematurely

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm feeling a bit curious about how `.subscribeOn()` actually works on `RxJava`.
I have this piece of code that works as intended:

```
 return endpoints.getRecentConversations(page)
                .map().flatMap().doOnNext() //etc etc...
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

I was reading [this](https://upday.github.io/blog/subscribe_on/) article, trying to understand what the difference between `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` when this line caught my eye:

> **Position does not matter**
>
> `subscribeOn` can be put in any place in the stream because it affects
>   only the time of subscription

Which sounds perfectly fine. But I was feeling a bit skeptical I decided to test it. So I changed the code above (switched lines 2 and 3):

```
 return endpoints.getRecentConversations(page)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map().flatMap().doOnNext() //etc etc...
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

As a result, I get an premature `onComplete()` on my subscriber. `onNext()` is never called and no errors are present in my logcat.

I can leave things the way they were, but I'd like to know why this is happening. Is it true that *position doesn't matter*? Is it something wrong with my code? [Here's how my code looks](https://gist.github.com/feresr/13c4a05d1e67dddbb87e1c3934a9c857)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the position does matter a lot in RxJava, It's called upstream & downstream.

It's because you are subscribing to a hot observable
Watch this video to understand it better: Common RxJava Mistakes
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdmkXL7XikQ&t=768s

There are two types of observables: Hot & cold.

> A “hot” Observable may begin emitting items as soon as it is created,
>   and so any observer who later subscribes to that Observable may start
>   observing the sequence somewhere in the middle. A “cold” Observable,
>   on the other hand waits until an observer subscribes to it before it
>   begins to emit items, and so such an observer is guaranteed to see the
>   whole sequence from the beginning.

Comment: Great talk, worth watching thanks. But I'm not subscribing to a hot observable, it's cold check my gist. And also Dan Lew says in the talk that the order of .subscribeOn doesn't matter. .observeOn is another story

Comment: Let me check it